# Camera follow geometry nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes, camera, parent

I have made a random curve in geometry nodes and need the camera to follow this curve.
I can get both an empty and an object to follow it but I just can't get the camera to stick to any of it.
I have tried with Child Of and with Parent but even though I see the empty or object move along the line, the camera doesn't move.
I have tried making an object with vertex point follow the line, and make the camera Child Of that vertex group but still doesn't work.

So how to do this?
Can't the camera stick to anything made in GN?

[image]

Comment: Please show us your setup with screenshots or a file (blend-exchange.com) so we can see what's going on.

Comment: I think it is here https://blend-exchange.com/b/J5QgVYRX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add Plane, Parent (three point) Camera to Plane, add GeoNodes to the Plane ...

[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: Could be helpful for Rotation https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abjIKm_UHNo

Comment: Thank you so much :) It works just like I wanted it to :)